# Add a new column in table with a sequence - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence, alter

I have a table that has 60 million rows of data. I would like to introduce a new column say "id" for the table that is an auto incremented sequence.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Persons VALUES ('abc', 'def');
INSERT INTO Persons VALUES ('abcd', 'ghi');

CREATE SEQUENCE "PERSON_SEQUENCE" START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD (PERSONID NUMBER);

UPDATE persons SET personid = PERSON_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
```

In the above sql statements, I am able to create a sequence then alter the table and update it.

Since the amount of data I need to update is large.. I would like to perform this with as much low cost as possible.

I am trying to do so something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD (PERSONID NUMBER DEFAULT(PERSON_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL));
```

but the above does not work. Oracle throws me the below error:

> Error starting at line :
>
> 1 in command - ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD (PERSONID NUMBER
>   DEFAULT(PERSON_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL)) Error report -
>
> **ORA-00984:** column not allowed here
>   00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

However this works:

```
ALTER TABLE PERSONS ADD (PERSONID NUMBER DEFAULT(0));
```

Could some one help me with how I can achieve to alter a table (create a new column) and populate the column with a seq id both in a single sql. Thank you!

Comment: which version of Oracle are you trying this on?

Comment: FYI ...Oracle 12c onwards supports adding sequence value as column default

Comment: @shrek I use Oracle version 11g (11.2.0.4)

Comment: Do you know how many CPUs the database machine has?

Comment: If you found a solution to this, please accept the answer or add one of your own.

Answer (score 7):

For a table with 60 million rows, I would not do an add column + insert, but create the table new:

```
RENAME persons TO persons_old;

CREATE TABLE Persons (
  personid   number,
  LastName   varchar(255),
  FirstName  varchar(255)
); 

INSERT INTO persons (personid, lastname, firstname)
SELECT person_sequence.nextval, lastname, firstname
  FROM persons_old;

DROP TABLE persons_old;
```

If this is still taking too long, speak to your DBA about `ALTER TABLE NOLOGGING` and `INSERT /*+ APPEND */` and `PARALLEL DML`.

EDIT: Ah, yes, for 60 million you could even increase the cache size of the sequence for the initial assignment:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE PERSON_SEQUENCE CACHE 1000;
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

alter table PERSONS add (PERSON_ID number default PERSON_SEQ.nextval);